# Using tuple efficiently with strip()

Tags: python, python-3.x, split, tuples, strip

Consider a basic `tuple` used with the built-in method `str.startswith()`:

```
>>> t = 'x','y','z'
>>> s = 'x marks the spot'
>>> s.startswith( t )
True
```

It seems a loop is required when using a tuple with `str.strip()`:

```
>>> for i in t: s.strip(i)
... 
' marks the spot'
'x marks the spot'
'x marks the spot'
```

This seems wasteful perhaps; is there a more efficient way to use  tuple items with `str.strip()`? `s.strip(t)` seemed logical, however, no bueno.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stripping a string is a very different usecase from testing if a string starts with a given text, so the methods differ materially in how they treat their input.

`str.strip()` takes one string, which is treated as a *set* of characters; the string will be stripped of each of those characters in the set; as long as the string starts of ends with a character that is a member of the set, that starting or ending character is removed, until start and end are free of any characters from the given set.

If you have a tuple join it into one string:

```
s.strip(''.join(t))
```

or pass it in as a string literal:

```
s.strip('xyz')
```

Note that this means something *different* from using `str.strip()` with each individual tuple element!

Compare:

```
>>> s = 'yxz_middle_zxy'
>>> for t in ('x', 'y', 'z'):
...     print(s.strip(t))
... 
yxz_middle_zxy
xz_middle_zx
yxz_middle_zxy
>>> print(s.strip('xyz'))
_middle_
```

Even if you chained the `str.strip()` calls with individual character, it would still not produce the same output because the `str.strip()` call:

```
>>> for t in ('x', 'y', 'z'):
...     s = s.strip(t)
... 
>>> print(s)
xz_middle_zx
```

because the string never started or ended in `x` or `z` when those character were stripped; `x` only ended up at the start and end because the `y` character was stripped in a next step.